# why does undefined keep appearing in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, frontend

image of chrome developer tool
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HllKO.png

Why does chrome developer tool keeps showing undefined

Comment: Because `console.log` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Also duplicate of [node.js displays “undefined” on the console](/q/8457389/4642212) and [Why do i get extra undefined in last row of my output?](/q/65325666/4642212).

Comment: But i have passed "Hello" as a parameter